# Is there a way to raise r2_score of ANN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I make a ANN model using my data like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOWgZ.png)
Columns[1] is morning temperature average

next is morning humdity, region, UV, morning Ozone average, morning NO2 average, afternoon ozone concentration

```
X = df[[df.columns[0], df.columns[1], df.columns[3], df.columns[4],df.columns[5]]]
y = df[df.columns[6]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
```

then, i make a ANN model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(units=5, input_dim = 5, kernel_initializer='normal',activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 15)
```

```
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

but, when i check r2_score, the score is minus

```
r2_score(y_test, prediction)
```

`-1.424108360733626`

i don't know how to make it positive number

i change a parameters, like 'kernel_initializer', 'activation' and 'Epoch'.

but all the result is negative number.

and i also change a units of Dense, but the result was same

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which r2 score do you get for a training set?

Comment: You can try using `Normalization(tf.keras.layers.Normalization())` to the rows of the dataset and set the Adam `learning_rate=0.1`. You can also try by changing the units in the Dense layer or use `mean_absolute_error` as loss if the dataset contains outliers. Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression) for help.